# Minimum number of increment-other operations to make all array elements equal

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I am reading [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-increment-operations-make-array-elements-equal/) question in geek for geeks site.

The question is about finding the number of minimum moves in an array so all elements are equal.

> We are given an array consisting of n elements. At each operation you
>   can select any one element and increase rest of n-1 elements by 1. You
>   have to make all elements equal performing such operation as many
>   times you wish. Find the minimum number of operations needed for this.

```
Examples:

Input : arr[] = {1, 2, 3}
Output : Minimum Operation = 3
Explanation : 
operation | increased elements | after increment
    1     |    1, 2            | 2, 3, 3
    2     |    1, 2            | 3, 4, 3
    3     |    1, 3            | 4, 4, 4

Input : arr[] = {4, 3, 4}
Output : Minimum Operation = 2
Explanation : 
operation | increased elements | after increment
     1    |    1, 2           | 5, 4, 4
     2    |    2, 3           | 5, 5, 5
```

The link explains we have to use the formula `minOperation = sum - (n * small)` to get the answer, where sum is the total of all elements in array, n is the number of elements in array and small is the least element in array.

Can you please help me in understanding what the formula indicates `minOperation = sum - (n * small)`? and how it solves the question?

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? If it does, your indices are all off by one.

Comment: Think of a bar chart of the array, where `sum` is the area of the shaded portion. `n*small` is the area below the baseline made by the smallest element. The difference, `minOperation`, is the number of area units you need to remove to make all the elements match the baseline (which rises with every operation).

Comment: A solid algorithm would probably be to always select the second smallest element in the array, increasing the number of elements that match the baseline one by one.

Comment: "If we took a closer look at each operation as well problem statement we will find that increasing all n-1 element except the largest one is similar to decreasing the largest element only. So, the smallest elements need not to decrease any more and rest of elements will got decremented upto smallest one. In this way the total number of operation required for making all elements equal will be ..." - that seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @Dukeling, yes but how that formula is derived based on the statement, I am not able to get that

Comment: I can give a very clear explanation to this, give me a minute.

Comment: Decreasing an element B down to A takes B-A operations, decreasing 2 elements B and C down to A takes B-A + C-A = B+C-2*A operations. Generalise and you have your formula.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit 1:**
To relate to this solution better, it is good to mention what user *Dukeling* has said in his comments. That is, increasing all other elements except the largest element is similar to decreasing only the largest element.

---

Now, imagine you are trying to level many columns of bricks. Each column of bricks can be of different level:

In order to level all column of bricks, you always pick the highest column and remove 1 brick at a time.

Repeat the process till all columns are levelled.
[image]

Those coloured in yellow are the bricks you need to remove to achieve your goal.(they also mean the number of operations you need to perform to reach your goal)

In order to count number of red bricks, you use a simple formula similar to area of rectangle, that is length x breadth.

```
min x number of columns = all the red bricks (to be remained untouched)

sum of all bricks - number of red bricks = all yellow bricks
```

Hence you have the formula:

```
minOperation = sum - (n * small)
```

[image]

Number of yellows = minimum number of operations needed to make all array elements equal.

Comment: This is the best explanation I found, great visual representations too! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use a simple formula:

Sum of array element - (size of the array * minimum element from the array)

Example
array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} n = 5 // size of array

sum = 15, min = 1

ans = sum - (min * n) = 10

[uniformarray](/questions/tagged/uniformarray) [array](/questions/tagged/array) [bricksproblem](/questions/tagged/bricksproblem)

Answer (score -1):

i have solve this question using binary search!

```
def main():
#codechef question SALARY 
t = input()
t = int(t)
while t > 0:
    n = input()
    n = int(n)
    val = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))
    initial_sum = sum(val)
    min_value = min(val)
    left = 0
    right = 10000000000
    while left <= right:
        mid = (left + right) // 2
        may_be = initial_sum + (mid * (n-1))
        mean = may_be / n
        diff = mean - min_value
        if diff == mid:
            break
        elif diff < mid:
            right = mid - 1
        else:
            left = mid + 1
    print(mid)
    t -= 1
```

if **name** == '**main**':
    main()